# Increasing and decreasing the input quantity using Hyva / AlpineJS

Tags: magento2, quantity, input, hyva, alpine.js

I'm working on the input using **Hyva**, so with **AlpineJS**. I would need to understand how I have to do to make the input look like in the image using the + and - to increase or decrease the quantity.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the functional area of the + and -, below is an example of **AlpineJS** component to do that (the styling is more relevant to **TailwindCSS** and not **AlpineJS**):

```
<div x-data="{counter: 0}">
    <button @click="counter = counter - (counter > 0)" > 
        <!-- (counter > 0) prevents negative values, if you want them replace it with 1 -->
        <span>-</span>
    </button>
    <input type="number" min="0" :value="counter" />
    <button @click="counter = counter + 1" > 
        <span>+</span>
    </button>
</div>
```